# Unable to have a real time key event in text area for unit cases in react

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, textarea

I have a text area component in my code. Initial value of the textarea is comments by default. I am able to simulate change on the component by

```
expect(component.find('.text-area').text()).toEqual('comments');
component.find('textarea').simulate('change', { target: { value: 'Comments'}});
expect(component.find('.text-area').text()).toEqual('Comments');
```

It is running fine till this point. But when I am trying to have a real time character it fails. I have tried

```
component.find('.text-area').simulate('keyDown', { which: keycode('k') });
```

I have referred many posts before posting this. Not able to find the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

keyDown simulation should only take keyCode value. Try it like this:

```
component.find('.text-area').simulate('keyDown', { keyCode: 'k'});
```

And the jsx should be like this:

```
<textarea
    className='text-area'
    onChange={(e) => {
        this.setState({ textArea: e.target.value });
    }}
    onKeyDown={(e) => {
        this.setState({ textArea: e.keyCode });
    }}
>
    {this.state.textArea}
</textarea>
```

Comment: I tried. When I am printing the value using console.log(component.find('.text-area').text()); it still shows Comments

Comment: Yes @salix. I have the onKeyDown handler

Comment: I tried it on locally, and edited my answer. This way it passes the test.